# Realm Auto Migration kotlin android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, realm, realm-migration

**Hi Developers**
I am working on E-commerce based application and use realm as a local database. Actually everytime we release new version of app we have need to add or remove some database feilds like String ,list, Int etc .
Now i want to update realm schema version only, and if there is any change in Realm model class will auto detect and update, No need to manual update.
If someone have auto migration code please send me or any suggestions.
I checked official realm documentation and stack over flow but not succeed .
Thanks in Advance .

Comment: I have a realm Auto migration code snippet if some one needs then drop a comment i give them